# Printing asterisk char prints broken character in C

Tags: c, printing, char, printf

I am attempting to print an asterisk, but it prints a broken/special character in terminal print.
I initialize the char variable to be empty

```
char asterisk = "";
```

and set it depending on the result of:

```
asterisk = (cube % 3 == 0) ? "*\0" : "";
```

and print it using

```
printf("%d%c\n", cube, asterisk);
```

Instead, I get the output

```
Enter an integer
2000
0§
1
8
27§
64
125
216§
343
512
729§
1000
1331
1728§
```

I tried to add an escape sequence in the assignment of the non-empty char in the tertiary operator line, but this didn't solve the issue. I apologize for any simple errors, I am pretty new to C.

Comment: @Mureinik has answered your question already. In the future, please show us a more complete example of the code you're working with. In particular how `asterisk` was declared. If it was declared as a `char`, assigning a string literal to it should have given you a compiler error or warning.

Comment: Got it, will update post with the declaration @chris

Comment: Yes. Compiling even the most basic program to test this (`int main(void) { char asterisk = ""; }`) raises warnings when compiled. It _does_ compile and the resulting program runs, but that doesn't mean it's right. C is rather permissive that way.What starts out as a warning can either become an error that prevents compilation, or a runtime fault of the compiled executable.

Comment: Please, post a complete example as recommended in [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  You have many syntactic errors in the samples you put to get an idea of what are you asking about or what is failing.  Post tested (and failing, but tested that the posted code fails as stated in the text) code, not what you write, which has many errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your asterisk isn't a `char`, it's a string (`char*`, denoted by double quotes). If you want to print it correctly, you should use `%s`, not `%c`:

```c
printf("%d%s\n", cube, asterisk);
/* Here --^ */
```

Comment: I corrected it to %s, and it does not print anything including the value of cube now. I updated my post with the way I declared asterisk if that would help deduce this problem.

Comment: @QuantumBlink You also have to change the type, `char asterisk` -> `char *asterisk`.

Comment: @QuantumBlink the definition of `asterisk` is wrong - you defined it as a `char`, but you're assigning a string literal to it. With those values, it should be defined as a `char*`.